# Spam filtering for email in Flask Security module

Tags: python, flask

I am facing some spam issues in my application registration. It is done by Flask security module. How can I customise the registration method to include a spam filtering before writing data to database ? I already hooked the method @user_registered.connect_via to send mail. Need your help to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Versions used :

Python - 2.7
Flask - 0.10.1
Flask-Security - 1.7.5

Answer (score 0):

It works well using the code given below :

```
from flask_security.forms import ConfirmRegisterForm

security = Security(app, datastore,
                confirm_register_form=ExtendedConfirmRegisterForm)


class ExtendedConfirmRegisterForm(ConfirmRegisterForm):
   def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       super(ExtendedConfirmRegisterForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

   def validate(self):
      if not super(ExtendedConfirmRegisterForm,self).validate():
          return False

      if is_spam(self.email.data):
         logging.error('It is a spam mail %s'%self.email.data)
         self.email.errors.append('This mail id is a Spam')
         return False

      return True
```